# spring - populating @ModelAttributes directly from @RequestParams

Tags: java, spring

i have a register view that takes `@RequestParams`and sets the fields in a form. There are 2 fields `name` and `phone`. If I call the view as `/register?name=myname&phone=mynumber`, it sets the fields to the correct values, but i have to click 'Submit' button to submit the form. The form submit action happens in the same view. what should i do so that when i have called the view with all the required parameters, it will automatically submit and make an entry in the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is, when you request `/register?name=myname&phone=mynumber`, the parameters are used to set the fields, but the `@ModelAttribute`s in your controller are being initialised to empty objects. Only when you click the 'Submit' button does the values bind to the specific fields in the `@ModelAttribute`s. Then you (apparently in the same controller) process the form, (probably validate it) and update your records (DB).

Comment: But I want to know if there's any other way i can directly populate the `@ModelAttribute`